# Limits of norms and deriviative as linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I'm self-studying Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds and he introduces the derivative by first looking at it as a linear transformation, $Df(a) = \lambda$, saying that for a differentiable function $f:R^n\to R^m$ there is a linear transformation $\lambda:R^n \to R^m$ such that $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\|f(a+h)-f(a)-\lambda(h)\|}{\|h\|}=0$.

I'm rusty on my limits, and I've been trying to figure out why it's not the case that:
$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\|f(a+h)-f(a)-\lambda(h)\|}{\|h\|}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\|f(a)-f(a)-\lambda(h)\|}{\|h\|}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\|\lambda(h)\|}{\|h\|} = 0$

I know this is incorrect because of the following example he gives, but I'm not sure why it's not correct.

> For the moment let us consider the function $f: R^2 \to R$ defined by $f(x,y) = \sin x$.  Then $Df(a,b) = \lambda$ satisfies $\lambda(x,y) = (\cos a)\cdot x$.

Then in the proof:

> $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\|\sin (a+h) - \sin a - (\cos a) \cdot h\|}{\|h\|} = 0$

But if my incorrect understanding were correct then:

$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\|\sin (a+h) - \sin a - (\cos a) \cdot h\|}{\|h\|} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\|(\cos a) \cdot h\|}{\|h\|} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\|(\cos a)\| \cdot \|h\|}{\|h\|} = \|\cos a\|$

So why isn't it the case that the condition for the linear transformation can simply be reduced to $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\|\lambda(h)\|}{\|h\|} = 0$ and how do I correctly compute the limit inside the norm?

Comment: You can't selectively distribute a limit like that and your example shows why: you get results that don't make sense. You have to apply it to the whole collective term or to each part individually (if the limits make sense). You can't mix and match.

Comment: Apparently my review of limits was too brief.  It makes sense now that distributing the limit like that wouldn't work, but I'm still not seeing how the the equation ends up being $0$ in the limit.

Comment: Well to see how Spivak's comes to zero, note that $\sin(a+h) = \sin(a)\cos(h)+\cos(a)\sin(h)$ Then the numerator is $$\sin(a)\cos(h)+\cos(a)\sin(h)-\sin(a)-\cos(a)h = \sin(a)(\cos(h)-1)+\cos(a)(\sin(h)-h).$$ So what you want to evaluate then is $$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\left(\sin(a)\frac{\cos(h)-1}{h}+\cos(a)\frac{\sin(h)-h}{h}\right).$$ The first term will go to $0$ since $\cos$ has $0$ for a derivative at the origin. The second term will go to zero because $\frac{\sin(h)-h}{h} = \frac{\sin(h)}{h}-1$ and $\frac{\sin(h)}{h}$ will go to $1$.

Comment: Ah, ok.  It makes much more sense now, thank you.

Comment: You're very welcome :)